# How to compile to custom libdir path postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to custom libdir to bindir. by default prefix is root. so sub-dir (bin, lib, include, share) will inside prefix. after i custom it. i got this error. like i wrong to use --libdir command. but it tells to put absolute path.

> 58P01: could not open directory "C:postgresql-14.uilin":

```
./configure --prefix="c:/postgresql/build" --libdir="c:/postgresql/build/bin"
make 
make install
```

Comment: You don't use `configure` and `make` to build on Windows unless you are using Cygwin. Read the documentation!

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe i success compile with that command. i can edit prefix. and so on. sory2. i compile with msys2-mingw64. but the libdir seems dont work.

Comment: Ah, ye, with MinGW that is also the correct procedure. The path in the error message seems to have nothing to do with the `libdir`. I thought that in MSYS, you write paths like `/c/postgresql/lib`.